# Google Maps for Flutter iOS Swift setup

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, flutter

The instructions for setting up the official Google Maps for Flutter plugin include adding the Google API key to the AppDelegate.m file:

Specify your API key in the application delegate ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h" 
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

My flutter project has an AppDelegate.swift file instead of an AppDelegate.m file and I'm not sure how to add the required key, as the syntax is different:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: were you able to launch the app successfully after this?

Comment: Yes. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add your API key as follows:

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps // Add this line!

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")  // Add this line!
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/README.md#ios

Answer (score 10):

One more thing, Dont forget to add below line on **ios/Runner/Info.plist**

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```